# Добавить новый склад в приложении "Управление запасами" облака retair.ru

Tags: алгоритм, оптимизация, методология

Я открыл новый филиал. Как добавить новую точку продаж в настройках приложения "Управление запасами" облака retair.ru ?

Comment: данный вопрос связан с программированием? если нет, то вам лучше обратиться в службу технической поддержки того, что вы написали.

Comment: Эх Ковальски, Ковальски...а не спамер ли вы случаем? :-)

Comment: Три тега и ни один не имеет ничего общего с вопросом. Не надо так.

Answer (score 0):

Добавление новой точки осуществляется в 6 шагов:

1. Создать новую цепочку перемещений
2. Задать основной склад новой точки продаж
3. Задать все учетные склады новой точки продаж
4. Задать все дочерние подразделения (с которых идет продажа товаров этой точки)
5. Установить настройки формирования рабочего ассортимента новой точки продаж
6. Установить настройки глубины запаса товаров в новой точке продаж

**1. Создание новой точки продаж**
Заходите в меню "Конфигурация УТЗ".

Переходите в подменю "Цепочки перемещений".

Далее, нажимая "плюсик" добавляете новое плечо распределения. Нужно указать логистическую схему, с какого центрального склада будет распределяться товар на новую точку и в качестве получателя - новую точку продаж.
[image: Плечо распределения]

**2. Задать основной склад новой точки продаж**
Переходите в подменю "Основные склады точек продаж".
В выпадающем списке выбираете основной склад.
Данная настройка требуется для документооборота, документы перемещений товара с центрального склада пойдут на этот склад.

**3. Задать все учетные склады новой точки продаж**
Переходите в подменю "Учетные склады точек продаж".
Плюсиком добавляете все склады новой точки продаж.

**4. Задать все дочерние подразделения (с которых идет продажа товаров этой точки)**
Переходите в подменю "Учетные подразделения".
Плюсиком добавляете все подразделения, с которых идет продажа в новой точке.

**5. Установить настройки формирования рабочего ассортимента новой точки продаж**
Заходите в меню "[Рабочий ассортимент](https://apps.retair.ru/apps/working-assortment)".
[image: Рабочий ассортимент]
Далее, в списке слева кликнув на новую точку продаж, устанавливаете границы включения товаров в рабочий ассортимент.
[image: Границы включения в рабочий ассортимент]

**6. Установить настройки глубины запаса товаров в новой точке продаж**
И, наконец, в меню [Настройки перемещений](https://apps.retair.ru/apps/subsidiary-settings) устанавливаете минимальную и максимальную оборачиваемость в днях для новой точки продаж.
[image: Глубина запасов]